# warning: already initialized constant VERIFY_PEER

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I try to start the server I get the following warning:

```
/Users/sumitkalra1984/MVP/config/initializers/devise.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant VERIFY_PEER
```

My devise file:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if Rails.env.development?
```

How do I find where the constant is already defined, and how do I overwrite that definition?

Comment: Post the entire content of your devise file, also check your environment and application files in config folder.

Comment: thnx for the editing @toro2k...

Comment: nd @matt ok i m posting entire content of my device.rb file nd ofcourse environment and application files content.

Comment: Still curious about this question. Did you find the answer?

Comment: @robyoder sorry i can't find its answer yet...:(

Answer (score 10):

While I cannot find where else the constant is initialized, you can silence the warning by wrapping that line in a silence_warnings block.

```
silence_warnings do
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE unless Rails.env.production?
end
```

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-silence_warnings

Comment: Note: I also changed the end of the line to 'unless Rails.env.production?' because I was getting the warning while running tests as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke `OpenSSL::SSL.send(:remove_const, :VERIFY_PEER)` before to unset the constant, set it as you need it, and restore it to its original value afterwards. Here is example code [from a gist](https://gist.github.com/siruguri/66926b42a0c70ef7119e):

```
prev_setting = OpenSSL::SSL.send(:remove_const, :VERIFY_PEER)
OpenSSL::SSL.const_set(:VERIFY_PEER, OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)

# HTTP requests with DISABLED certificate verification go here.

OpenSSL::SSL.send(:remove_const, :VERIFY_PEER)
OpenSSL::SSL.const_set(:VERIFY_PEER, prev_setting)
```

**Source and attribution:** The solution comes from [a comment by @sameers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113422#comment47412538_1113614) on Stack Overflow. Licenced under CC-BY-SA 4.0 as per the Stack Overflow user contribution licensing policy. The gist is assumed to be part of that as the author indicated their original intent of publishing it in a Stack Overflow comment.