# How do I make HTTParty ignore SSL?

Tags: ruby, ssl, httparty

I'm using a local server to test an application, and make requests to that server from my own machine.

The test server's SSL is bad, and HTTParty throws errors because of that. From what I read, HTTParty should ignore SSL by default, but when I try to do this:

```
HTTParty.get( "#{ @settings.api_server }#{ url }" ).parsed_response
```

It throws this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError at /
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

How do I make it ignore the SSL?

Comment: change the api URI to `http` instead of `https` or remove port 443 if that's specified?

Comment: See here - https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/93

Comment: Duh, using http instead was fine, tnx Mike! I had seen that issue your referring to, maerics, if I understand that little talk correctly I shouldn't have gotten these errors in the first place, that's why I posted this question actually, I was clueless.

Comment: If you have installed Ruby with RVM as a binary and OpenSSL with Homebrew, then there's a mismatch between these two. See this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901864/troubleshooting-ssl-certificates-ruby-mac-os-x-yosemite/33035529#33035529

Answer (score 71):

In the latest HTTParty, you can use the verify option to disable SSL verification;

```
HTTParty.get( "#{ @settings.api_server }#{ url }", :verify => false ).parsed_response
```

Comment: httparty-0.13.7 - no luck

Comment: I tried with 0.13.7 and your suggestion worked fine.  My call was a little simpler:  HTTParty.get(url, :verify => false)

Comment: thanks for that answer! i'm curious tho, what causes that to work?

Answer (score 37):

To make *HTTParty* always skip SSL cert verification, and not have to specify this in every call:

```
require 'httparty'
HTTParty::Basement.default_options.update(verify: false)

HTTParty.get("#{@settings.api_ssl_server}#{url1}")
HTTParty.get("#{@settings.api_ssl_server}#{url2}")
HTTParty.get("#{@settings.api_ssl_server}#{url3}")
# ...
```

You can also do this scoped to a class when including *HTTParty* as a module:

```
require 'httparty'

class Client
  include HTTParty
  default_options.update(verify: false)
end

Client.get("#{@settings.api_ssl_server}#{url1}")
Client.get("#{@settings.api_ssl_server}#{url2}")
Client.get("#{@settings.api_ssl_server}#{url3}")
```

Or

```
require 'httparty'

module APIHelpers
  class Client
    include HTTParty
    default_options.update(verify: false)
  end
end
World(APIHelpers)

Client.get("#{@settings.api_ssl_server}#{url1}")
Client.get("#{@settings.api_ssl_server}#{url2}")
Client.get("#{@settings.api_ssl_server}#{url3}")
```

Comment: worked for me with the latest version of httparty 0.13.7. thanks (Y)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to still send your certificates, use this flag:

```
verify_peer: false
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMO. I don't understand why anyone would want to completely turn off SSL, especially in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

This may be totally off base, as I'm new to Ruby, but this is what worked for me when other solutions wouldnt

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Additional ways of doing this, if you get a 'dynamic constant assignment' (pulled [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1113614/26510))

```
OpenSSL::SSL.const_set(:VERIFY_PEER, OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
```

Comment: This results in a syntax error: `dynamic constant assignment`

Comment: More info on this here - This should only be used for development or testing, NEVER in production:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1113614/26510

Comment: Added this code at `env.rb` and worked like a charm for me!