# Unable to bypass SSL Certificate Error with HTTParty in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I'm getting an SSL Certificate error when I try to access a web server using HTTParty. This is the error I got originally.

> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
>   certificate verify failed

I tried to correct his by updating default options. The code is below.

```
class Coursera
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses'
    default_params fields: "smallIcon,shortDescription", q: "search"
    format :json
    default_options.update(verify: false)

    def self.for term
      get("", query: { query: term})["elements"]
    end
end
```

However, this resulted in another error, which is confounding me.

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
>   default_options.update(verify: false)

Can someone explain why this error is occurring and how I can bypass the SSL in order to obtain the results of the query?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/22695651/1657377

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end default_options.update(verify: false)` 
because of this line

```
HTTParty.get(get("", query: { query: term})["elements"])
```

There is a missing bracket at the end. Actually, you don't need to call `get` on `HTTParty`. Replace

```
HTTParty.get(get("", query: { query: term})["elements"])
```

with

```
get("",query: { query: term})["elements"])
```

Compare your file with https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course1-module3/blob/master/app/models/coursera.rb

Back to the SSl error now.

From https://gist.github.com/mislav/5026283

> The reason why you might get certificate errors in Ruby 2.0 when talking > HTTPS is because there isn't a default certificate bundle that OpenSSL 
>   (which was used when building Ruby) trusts.

Instead of disabling SSL, you can get around the error by installing the certificate.

The gist also contains information on how to install the certificate bundle manually.

Hope this helps!