# Ruby Sinatra create post request without PEM and OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

Tags: ruby, ssl, sinatra

I try create POST request with SSL but without OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE because it is opend up security attacks and without PEM certificate.
But I catch problems, my ruby code for send POST request:

```
post '/test/test1' do
  cross_origin
  post_data = request.body.read
  res_Data = JSON.parse(post_data)
  userName = res_Data['username']

  @responseFromServer=''
  uri = URI('https://test.com/test1')
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
                  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https',
                  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.request_uri
    request.basic_auth 'aa', 'bb'
    request.body = {'username' =>userName}.to_json
    response = http.request request
    @responseFromServer = response.body.to_s
  end
  newJson = JSON.parse(@responseFromServer)

  status_msg = newJson['status']['status_msg']
  if (status_msg == "Success")
    return 'true'
  end
    return 'false'
end
```

It is method worked but he use OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE. How to create method for send POST request without OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE and PEM sertificate?

**EDIT**
**SSL/HTTPS request**
Update: There are some good reasons why this code example is bad. It introduces a potential security vulnerability if it's essential you use the server certificate to verify the identity of the server you're connecting to. There's a fix for the issue though!

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://secure.com/")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
response.body
response.status
response["header-here"] # All headers are lowercase
```

**SSL/HTTPS request with PEM certificate**

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://secure.com/")
pem = File.read("/path/to/my.pem")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(pem)
http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem)
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
```

My question: How to create POST method without PEM and **OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE**?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113422/how-to-bypass-ssl-certificate-verification-in-open-uri

Comment: @karlingen You mean what I need use **OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE**? It is works but I need use **POST request without OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE**

Comment: @karlingen Or if I use **OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE** it is solves the problem of security?

Comment: I honestly can not understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: What are the reasons not to use PEM?

Comment: So the question is, do you want to use SSL or not? Because if you do VERIFY_NONE you at least have self-signed certs, you are still exposed to MiTM attacks though. If you do VERIFY_PEER and pass a good cert then you are doing it properly. But from your post you don't want to do neither, so I guess that you want your stuff in the clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite misleading, but I try my best to figure it out. Here is my advise:

**Do you want to connect to a service that is only available through https and you do not care if the certificate is valid?**

Then you can use `:verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` when initializing the `Net::HTTP` client.
You will have some kind of transport security, but you cannot be sure the server you are talking to is the one you think it is. You are vulnerable.

**Do you want to connect to a service that is available both through https and http, and you do not care about transport security?**

Then you should use the `http://...` endpoint.

**Do you want to connect to a service and you care about transport security?**

Then you should definitely use the `https://...` endpoint.
Do not override `:verify_mode`!
If you are getting certificate verification errors, make sure you have the correct Certificate Authority installed on your system.