# OpenSSL Certificate Requirements Easing in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, smtp

I have a Rails app that's being a little contrary.  When I execute this command:

```
[1] pry(main)> Jobs::TestEmail.new.execute(to_address: "destination@domain.tld")
```

It returns this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname "smtp.domain.tld" does not match the server certificate
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/openssl/ssl.rb:394:in `post_connection_check'
```

I don't have any trouble sending emails normally with this server via clients OR [`swaks`](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) for example... It's only happening in Rails.  Is there something extra that Rails is doing that I can disable or change the restriction level that will eliminate this issue?

Comment: You want to ignore OpenSSL's warning that the host you're connecting to doesn't have a valid certificate? [That's bad and you shouldn't do that but it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113422/how-to-bypass-ssl-certificate-verification-in-open-uri). As for why it doesn't happen with swaks or "via clients" (what does that even mean?), they probably aren't using TLS.

Comment: What is the purpose of this job?  Is it to be run in a test environment only?

Comment: Here are some more details as to why this question arose: https://serverfault.com/questions/942499/smtp-problems-due-to-cn-vs-sni-on-the-certificate - perhaps this will shine some light onto the why and where.